# CSS nested flexbox fill height

Tags: html, css

What is wrong with the following code? I have a nested element

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='content'>
   
  </div>
</div>
<div class='bottom'>
  Bottom
</div>
```

And I would like to fill vertical space, When I nest it the nested Content cannot fill the space

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.parent {
  flex: 1; /* Fill remaining vertical space */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  flex: 1; /* Fill remaining vertical space */
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 10px; /* Add padding or adjust as needed */
}

.bottom {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='content'>
      Content

      <div class='parent'>
        <div class='content'>
          Content
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='bottom'>
        Bottom
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='bottom'>
      Bottom
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: .content is not a flexbox container so flex:1 to its child has no effect

Comment: @TemaniAfif oh! my bad! thank you. What about `overflow-y: auto`. If we add a lot of Content, I would like to have a scroll bar on the inner content.

Comment: Then you need to apply something, that limits the height the content is allowed to take, first of all. (With those multiple parent and content elements you have _nested_ into each other in the example right now, I would not know what that height could be supposed to be here though. You'll need to clarify what exactly you actually want to achieve here.)

Comment: I would like to fill the height as much as possible and the inner content has priority to expand, which means, If I don't nest I would like to see "bottom" at bottom of the page and If I nest, I would like to see two "bottom" at the bottom of the page. This is a React component and in a complex scenario they can be sibling and nested